# How can I remove dynamically added Lightning component from DOM on change of checkbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dynamic

I am adding multiple components dynamically in init, given the example of "TextBoxComponent". Conditionally I want to remove this component.

Main Component Markup:

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.init}" value="{!this}"/> 
  <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="chk" text="Add" change="{!c.handleChange}"/>     
  <div id="MainDiv" aura:id="MainDiv"></div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller Code:

```
 ({
init:function(component,event,helper){
var divCmp = component.find("MainDiv");
var divBody = divCmp.get("v.body");
$A.createComponent("c:TextBoxComponent",
                {
                    "Id" : "TBId",
                    "inputText" : "Enter Value",
                    "inputValue":"Test"                        
                }, 
                 function(newTB){
                   newCmp.set("v.body", newBody.concat(newTB));
                });
},   
})
```

TextBoxComponent Markup:

```
 <aura:component >
   <aura:attribute type="String" name="Id" />
   <aura:attribute type="String" name="inputText" />
   <aura:attribute type="String" name="inputValue" />

  <div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label">{!v.inputText}</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
      <ui:inputText aura:id="{!v.Id}" class="slds-input"   value="{!v.inputValue}" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Answered [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/82617/how-can-i-remove-a-lightning-component-from-the-dom)

But, in short:

```
init:handleChange(component,event,helper){
    var divCmp = component.find("MainDiv");
    var checked = component.find("chk").get("v.value");

    if(checked){

        $A.createComponent("c:TextBoxComponent",
                {
                    "Id" : "TBId",
                    "inputText" : "Enter Value",
                    "inputValue":"Test"                        
                }, 
                 function(newTB){
                   var body = divCmp.get("v.body");
                   body.push(newTB);
                   divCmp.set("v.body", body);
                });
    }else{

        divCmp.set("v.body", []);
    }
}
```